Proof of lemma 4.1.1 in Durrett's Probability
Lemma 4.1.1 of Durrett's Probability states that

If $Y$ is a conditional expectation of $X$ ($\in L^1$) given $\mathcal F$, then $Y$ is integrable.

And it proves this by considering the set $A = \{ Y > 0\} \in \mathcal F$, and then shows that
\begin{align}
\int_A Y \leq \int_A |X| && \int_{A^{\mathsf c}} - Y \leq \int_{A^{\mathsf c}} |X| \mathpunct,
\end{align}
but I just don't understand why go through all this effort when it follows simply from the definition of conditional expectation that since $\Omega \in \mathcal F$,
$$
\int Y = \int X  < \infty \mathpunct.
$$
Is this just an oversight on Durrett's part or am I missing something to do with the definition of integrability. As far as I am aware, it suffices to just show that the non-absolute integral is finite.
